# Can't Archive my app before release

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

my app has Google Maps in it and i'm Using Parse.com as well. so in the Valid Architectures in the Build Settings i have armv7 and armv7s added together. when i archive the app, i get the following error:

> ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/MyName/Documents/Workspace/AppName/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps for architecture armv7s
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i searched over here for solutions and i was able to eliminate it by removing armv7s from the Valid Architectures. However, when reading through the comments i learned that armv7s let's the app have full support for iphone 5. can anybody explain that? and is there a way that i can pass both armv7 and armv7s?